# parent children desde el segundo tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

cómo puedo utilizar el siguiente código, para que cambie los ids desde el segundo tr u omita el primer tr, ya que la tabla tiene un tr inicial que muestra los nombres de las columnas el cual no se manejan datos.

```
parent.children("tbody").children("tr").each(function(e){
       $(this).attr('id', (e));
});
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saca los nombres de las columnas del tbody y ponlos en el thead

Ejemplo

```
<table>
    <thead>
         Tr's nombres de columna (cabecera)
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        Tr's cuerpo de la tabla
    </tbody>
```

De esta forma utilizas las etiquetas que provee html para tal fin y evitas tener que saltar el primer tr

Comment: me funcionó a la primera, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a utilizar gt(), este te permite indicar de cuál empezar:

```
parent.children("tbody").children("tr:gt(0)").each(function(e){
       $(this).attr('id', (e));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

mira podrias hacer lo siguiente, al **tbody**  ponle un **id**,

```
 <tbody id="tb">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

Luego con `javascript` , usando `jquery` puedes darle estilo a los `tr` o hacer con ellos lo que desees

```
$("#tb").children("tr").each(function(index,obj){ // index te da las cant 0 1 2 3 ... y obj te da el objeto en si <tr>bbb</tr>  <tr>aaaa</tr>  

     if(index > 0 ){ //trabajas con los que index > 0 para omitir el primero
         $(obj).css('color','red')
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

El mismo método de .each tiene integrado un parametro para poder saber en que index vamos sobre los elementos que encuentra.

Hay que recordar que el método .each recorre un array de elementos que coincidan.

Simplemente sería poner como parametro index, y una condicional que valide que solo tome a partir del segundo tr.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('table').children("tbody").children("tr").each(function(index, e){
     if( index >= 1){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
     }
  });
});
```

```css
table tr td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="firstRow">
      <td>Primer fila</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="secondRow">
      <td>Segunda fila</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="thirdRow">
      <td>Tercer fila</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fourthRow">
      <td>Cuarta fila</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```